# Adobe Acrobat misinterprets pdfLaTeX hyperref mailto links as relative paths

Tags: hyperref, pdftex, links, acrobat

The following code works and produces a mailto link within a pdf document. However, when opened with Adobe Acrobat, the link becomes `file:///path/to/document/%22mailto:foo@bar.abc%22`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\href{"mailto:foo@bar.abc"}{Broken Link!}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way within LaTeX to encode mailto links to be more compatible with Adobe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't quote your URL:

```
\href{mailto:foo@bar.abc}{Good Link!}
```

Comment: Aha. Simple and obvious, so of course I spent forever trying to figure it out. Thanks!